# Theming spree rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, spree

I am working on a rails project using the spree ecommerce engine.

I am wanting to edit the links just above the search bar but can not find them in the partial _nav_bar.html.erb

I also can not find the Deface overrides or js code that adds these fields. In the _nav_bar partial I have

```
<nav id="top-nav-bar" class="columns omega ten">
  <ul id="nav-bar" class="inline" data-hook>
        <h2>This happens before</h2>
    <li id="search-bar" data-hook>
        <h2>This happens after</h2>
      <%= render :partial => 'spree/shared/search' %>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

And it results in the code:

```
<nav id="top-nav-bar" class="columns omega ten"><ul id="nav-bar" class="inline" data-hook>
<h2>This happens before</h2>
  <li><a href="/account">My Account</a></li>
  <li><a href="/user/logout">Logout</a></li>
<li id="search-bar" data-hook>
        <h2>This happens after</h2>
     ............
</nav>
```

Where do these two links come from? How do I edit them? Why are they not simply held in this partial?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it is an override of the `spree_auth_devise` extension. See [auth_shared_login_bar.rb](https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise/blob/master/app/overrides/auth_shared_login_bar.rb) where it inserts the links before `li#search-bar`